# HTTP POST request issue

Tags: c#, .net, http, post, client-server

I am sending a HTTP POST request to PHP server using `HttpWebRequest`.
My code works like this:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Create Post request.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="requestUrl">Requested url.</param>
    /// <param name="postData">Post data.</param>
    /// <exception cref="RestClientException">RestClientException</exception>
    /// <returns>Response message, can be null.</returns>
    public string Post(string requestUrl, string postData)
    {
        try
        {
            //postData ends with &
            postData = "username=XXX&password=YYYY&" + postData;

            byte[] data = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);

            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(requestUrl);
            request.Method = RequestMethod.Post.ToString().ToUpper();
            request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            request.ContentLength = data.Length;

            using (Stream stream = request.GetRequestStream())
            {
                stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
                stream.Flush();
            }

            string responseString;
            using (WebResponse response = request.GetResponse())
            {
                responseString = GetResponseString(response);
            }

            return responseString;
        }
        catch (WebException ex)
        {
            var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)ex.Response;
            if (httpResponse != null)
            {
                throw new RestClientException(GetExceptionMessage(httpResponse));
            }

            throw;
        }
    }
```

I am experiencing wierd behaviour. Every minute I am sending like 100 requests using this. But from time to time, this request is executed withou POST data. Then my PHP server returns error (because I am checking if request is POST and if it has any POST data).

This is a client/server communication. Computer with Windows Service application is connected to the internet using Wifi. Connection is sometimes really poor. Can this cause issue mentioned? How to make HTTP POST request secure against this behaviour.

Comment: Are you sure it's _your_ requests that have no POST data? It could be someone else scanning your server for vulnerabilities, sending other kinds of random requests.

Comment: And are you sure you always provide data (i.e. your `postData` could be empty/wrong)?

Comment: Please see "[Stack Overflow does not allow tags in titles](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/130208)"

Comment: @romkyns: I am sure that nobody is scanning my server because the error is logged by my client. Server is checking every HTTP request for post data and if they are missing server returns error header with error body. This error response is logged by my client application.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov: yes postData is never empty. This variable always contains at least username and password. Error requests logged by my client did not contain any POST data ($_POST is an empty array).

Comment: @JohnSaunders:  Thank you for your information. I will consider to change the title.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any "customized" behaviour you use, so why don't you use the `WebClient.UploadData` method? then you will know it is not something you are doing wrong

it does all of the "dirty" work for you, and you can add the content-type header as well.

look at that link for more info: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tdbbwh0a(v=vs.80).aspx

example:

```
public string Post(string requestUrl, string postData)
{
   WebClient myWebClient = new WebClient();
   myWebClient.Headers.Add("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
   byte[] data = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);
   byte[] responseArray = myWebClient.UploadData(requestUrl,data);
   return responseArray;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I dont really know why I choosed different approach. I will try to use the WebClient class.